# Raspberry PI External Case Connector

Tags: gpio, pi-4, electronics

I have a DIY project with a Raspberry Pie and a few sensors. I have them working, hardwired through a breadboard. As I'm mounting them to a case I would like to have a female connector that passes the power and data with the breadboard/raspberry pi and a male connector on the sensor wire.

Then if I have to replace a sensor I dont have to rewire anything. Just plug in a new one.

What would be the best type of connection and wire to use?

I looked at 2.54mm pitch JST connectors and CAT6 cable but I can't find anything to confirm if it would work correctly.

Comment: if the sensor works when connected through a breadboard, then almost any connector would work ... try RJ12 connector ... that way people will not plug ethernet cables into it

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I'll look into some RJ12 connectors.

Comment: @jsotola Just a small correction, RJ12 is referring to connector and usage. The connector is "Modular 6P6C". Ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.